# Using structs/classes to increase cache spatial locality?

Tags: java, c++, performance, caching

If one took say 1000 lines of computer code and instead of the variables being declared independently, they were grouped together (obviously this does depend on the variable sizes being used) into classes and structs, would this directly increase the cache spacial locality (and therefore reduce the cache miss rate)?

I was under the impression by associating the variables within a class/struct they would be assigned continuous memory addresses?

Comment: Which language are you talking about? Because Java and C++ are rather different languages.

Comment: In general, yes but it depends on the access pattern of the variables. If the total memory of heap allocated variables doesn't fit in a cache line, there might still be frequent cache misses.

Comment: it's too hard to say without more details about the specific problem whether the miss rate would be reduced.  But yes in general the contents of a struct will be allocated with contiguous addresses (at least for C and C++).

Comment: @Shams, assume our data could (if declared within a struct/class) fit within one cache line.

Comment: I just want to know if trying to encapsulate the variables (which would have been declared independently) into an over-arching structure (struct/class etc) could reduce cache misses.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas- my question was for both languages. If there are differences depending on which language, feel free to answer specific to one language.

Comment: If it were that easy, I'm sure someone would have done it...

Comment: Plain-old data in a struct will be contiguous, yes. But C++ containers and Java objects can have their data located anywhere in the heap.

Comment: @Chrisaycock, so a Java or C++ class doesn't store its member attributes in continuous memory?

Comment: @user997112: for C++ it's not guaranteed (I think, I might be wrong), but it is common, mostly because continuous memory is easy to allocate and free by the runtime.

Comment: Even if a Java class has its members in contiguous memory, members which are object references will be referring to objects that will in general not be anywhere in that contiguous block.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic, what if the class only contained primitive types/primitive type arrays, long[]?

Comment: Java arrays are stored in the heap, so, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about method-local variables, they are already contiguous on the stack, or strictly speaking in activation records which are all but invariably on the stack. If you are talking about references to Java objects, or pointers to dynamically allocated C++ objects, putting them into containing classes won't make any difference for another reason: the objects concerned will still be in arbitrary positions in the heap.

Answer (score 2):

Answering this question is not possible without making some quite unreasonable assumptions. Spatial locality is as much about algorithms as it is about data structures, so grouping logically related data elements together may be of no consequence or even worse based on an algorithm that you use.

For example, consider a representation of 100 points in 3D space. You could put them in three separate arrays, or create a 3-tuple struct/class, and make an array of these.

If your algorithm must get all three coordinates of each point at once on each step, the tuple representation wins. However, think what would happen if you wanted to build an algorithm that operates on each dimension independently, and paralelize it three-way among three independent threads. In this case three separate arrays would win hands down, because that layout would avoid false sharing, and improve spatial locality as far as the one-dimension-at-a-time algorithm is concerned.

This example shows that there is no "one size fits all" solution. Spatial locality should always be considered in the context of a specific algorithm; a good solution in one case could turn bad in other seemingly similar cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking whether to group local variables into explicitly defined structures, there is not going to be an advantage. Local variables are implemented in terms of [activation records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_record#Structure), which are usually closely related to the implementation of class structures, for any language that has both.

So, local variables should already have good spatial locality, unless the language implementation is doing something weird to screw it up.

You might improve locality by isolating large chunks of local state which isn't used during recursion into separate non-recursing functions. This would be a micro-optimization, so you need to inspect the machine code first to be sure it's not a waste of time. Anyway, it's unrelated to moving locals into a `class`.